# loading weights keras LSTM not working

Tags: keras, lstm

I am trying to load the weights from a Keras 1.0 Model into a Keras 2.0 model I created. I am sure the model architecture is exactly the same. The issues I am having is the load_weights() function is loading all the weights.

When I print the weights to a text file from the original model (loaded via load_model) and from the new model with load_weights() the later is missing many entry and are actually different.  This also shows itself when making predictions as the accuracy is lower.

This problem only occurs in my LSTM layers. The embedding layers is fine and the Dense layer is also fine.

Any thoughts? I can not use load_model() as the original saved model was done in keras 1.0 and I need to use keras 2.0

---

EDIT MORE:

I should note I think the issue is the internal states not being loaded. Let me explain though. When I use get_weights() on each layer and I print it too terminal or a file the original model outputs a much larger matrix.

After using load_weights and then get_weights and print the weight matrix is  missing many elements. I'm thinking it's the internal states.

Comment: Did you save the model using names? That might help.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Each layer has the default naming.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there was parameters for a compiled graph that were saved. I think it's safe to just port over the weights and continue training to let it catch up (maybe 1-2 epochs) if you can.

Gl